# Jenkins pod not starting: Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: installation, jenkins, kubernetes

Created PV and PVC in GKE. Jenkins POD is not starting after running helm command. It is showing in state Init:0/1 and deployment is also coming unavailable.
error message: Back-off restarting failed container.

Also refered to github but solution is not yet provided : https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/12901